# C++ read keyboard events

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard

I am new to C++ and I am trying to make a program that reads keystrokes.  This is a function I made that looks for a certain key.

```
void printKey(short vk)
{
    if ((GetAsyncKeyState(vk) >> 15) & 1)
    {
        LPWSTR key;
        GetKeyNameTextW(MapVirtualKeyW(vk, MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR) << 16, key, sizeof(key));
        wcout << key;
    }
}
```

I know that the key detection works as I have put code that just prints true or false inside of the if statement so I know that that part is working.  For example when I type "s" it prints true if I pass in the virtual key code 0x53 (virtual key code for s).  Once I knew that part worked I tried to use the MapVirtualKeyW and GeyKeyNameTextW functions to get the name of the key so I wouldn't have to hard code all of them in.  The code compiles but stops immediately after printing `Running....`

Here is the whole code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "User32.lib")

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::wcout;

void printKey(short vk)
{
    if ((GetAsyncKeyState(vk) >> 15) & 1)
    {
        LPWSTR key;
        GetKeyNameTextW(MapVirtualKeyW(vk, MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR) << 16, key, sizeof(key));
        wcout << key;
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Running...." << endl;

    while (true)
    {
        for (int i = 48; i <= 90; i++)
        {
            printKey(i);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the range 48-90 is for all the letter and number keys.  The idea is that whenever I press a key it should print to the console.

I am fairly confident the issue is in this block of code

```
LPWSTR key;
GetKeyNameTextW(MapVirtualKeyW(vk, MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR) << 16, key, sizeof(key));
wcout << key;
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: On a side note, `if ((GetAsyncKeyState(vk) >> 15) & 1)` can also be written as `if (GetAsyncKeyState(vk) & 0x8000)` or as `if (GetAsyncKeyState(vk) < 0)`

Comment: Also, there are more than just letters and numbers in the ASCII range 48..90, there are also punctuation characters, too. ASCII letters and numbers have the same numeric values as their corresponding virtual key codes, but virtual keys in the ASCII range 58-64 are undefined, so your loop is passing some invalid virtual keys to `GetAsyncKeyState()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the comments above, `GetKeynameText` needs a buffer for the key name, so instead of:

```
LPWSTR key;
GetKeyNameTextW(MapVirtualKeyW(vk, MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR) << 16, key, sizeof(key));
```

you want something like:

```
WCHAR key [128];
GetKeyNameTextW(MapVirtualKeyW(vk, MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR) << 16, key, sizeof(key) / sizeof (WCHAR));
```

You might also flush `wcout` after writing to it.

Comment: Note that the last parameter of `GetKeyNameText` is expressed in *characters*, not in bytes, so using `sizeof(key)` by itself is wrong when calling the Unicode version. Use `_countof(key)` or equivalent instead.

Comment: What does flushing it do and also how did you get the size 128?

Comment: Flushing `wcout` writes out any buffered characters, to ensure that you see them. 128, I made up.  It needs to be "long enough".